# onclick changing multiple form input values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm super new to Javascript and can't find the answer to my problem. I have many pages that are set up the exact same with a form and button on each one. When the user clicks the submit button I want the javascript to set the value of a hidden input. I have this working perfectly until I set up a second page. The second page needs to add a different value when the submit button is clicked. But only the last value in my javascript is working. It doesn't recognize the first value. I believe this would be easy to fix if I changed the Id on each submit button, but because of other code that I have this would cause hours of work.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

window.onload=function() {document.getElementById("atc").onclick=function() 
{document.forms[0].autosccartprice.value = "40.00";
document.forms[0].fwbcartprice.value = "118.00";
}}

//-->
</script>
```

This is the html on my first page, which works great.

```
<form action="https://www.mywebsite.com" method="post" 
class="buttonform">
<input type="hidden" name="price" id="fwbcartprice" value="" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="" class="addtocart3" id="atc" title="Add To Cart">
</form>
```

Here is the html on the second page, which doesn't work

```
<form action="https://www.mywebsite.com" method="post" 
class="buttonform">
<input type="hidden" name="price" id="autosccartprice" value="" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="" class="addtocart3" id="atc" title="Add To Cart">
</form>
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off using something like jQuery even if you're new to js; That aside however, are you sure that in your second example the form you're trying to execute with is the very first `form` tag on the page?  As you're targeting your form with `.forms[0]`, it might be catching a `form` tag preceeding it in the DOM.  I would suggest qualifying your form with its own id either way, and targeting that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to fill the hidden inputs but the form is already submitted.
So, first you need to halt the form submission, fill in the hidden fields then resubmit the form.

---

try this code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
   document.getElementsByClassName("buttonform")[0].addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     this.autosccartprice.value = "40.00";
     this.fwbcartprice.value = "118.00";
     this.submit();
   }
}
```

---

**Ps:** It would be better if you give each form a unique `ID` and then select each one with `getElementById()` method instead of `document.forms[i]`.

Comment: I've tried this code and many others and nothing is working. I'm very confused. Set each form with a unique ID and it still didn't work. And there are no other forms on the page. ??? Maybe I need to go about it a different way. Or I need to learn more about Javascript. There might be some other code making this not work right, since I'm using wordpress and I've seen this happen before. :(

Comment: i suggest you give a screenshot of your console when the code is being executed so it'll be easier to figure out the problem